# how to create a class that would accept vector holding any type of data?

Tags: c++, oop, vector, stl

This is my try:

```
template<typename T> class myClass {
 public:
  myClass(std::vector<T> v) {
  }
  std::vector<T> myVect;
};
```

but when I try to use it:

```
myClass myClassInstance(myVect);
```

it gives:

```
error: missing template arguments before 'myClassInstance'
```

Comment: `myClass` is a class template. So you need to instantiate it with a template argument.

Comment: Also note that a class template is not a class. `myClass<int>` is not the same type as `myClass<float>`. So you don't really have "a class that would accept vector holding any type of data".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to actually initialize your member variable to avoid a segmentation fault.

```
  myClass(const std::vector<T>& v) : myVect(v) {
  }

int main() {

    myClass<int> mc(std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
    std::cout << mc.myVect[0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the type of the template when creating the object:

```
myClass<some_type> myClassInstance(myVect);
```